# Unexpected symbol in vector in R

Tags: r

I just have a vector of some labels, however the last label "Not rated" is black, not green unlike the others, and i keep getting unexpected symbol

```
lbls <- c("Excellent", "Very Good", "Good", "Average", "Poor”, "Not Rated”)
```

Comment: you have two types of quotation marks, you should change the one at the end of Poor and the one at the end of Not Rated to match the others

Comment: worked out, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the quote at the end of "poor" is different than the others.  Its a matter of ” vs "
try

```
lbls <- c("Excellent", "Very Good", "Good", "Average", "Poor", "Not Rated")
```